# Disable current day in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can i disable current date selection in jquery datatable.

```
    $('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());

            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate <= today) {
                //If the selected date was 
                $('#Date').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [bin](http://jsbin.com/jeponi/edit?html,js,output). Add a similar logic to check `selected datetime and current datetime` inorder to whether or not to make selection.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to hide the button:

```
.ui-datepicker-current{display: none !important;}
```

OR use [showButtonPanel](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showButtonPanel) setting to hide the button panel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I just fixed this like below,

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false,
       minDate: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1)

    });
```

Thanks for quick reply folks